# Using Postman variables in team environment

Tags: postman

We are using Postman to test a web-api that our team is working on.  We have Postman Pro, so we're using a shared team environment. The problem is we need a way of using test environment variables WITHOUT stepping on each other's toes.

We're using a basic CRUD pattern for our tests:

1. **Create** a resource using a POST request, with Javascript in the "Tests" script that saves the ID of the newly created resource to an environment variable
2. **Read** that same resource using a GET request, that relies on the env variable that was set in step #1 to get the resource ID
3. **Update** that same resource using a PUT request, that again relies on the env variable that was set in step #1 to get the resource ID
4. Repeat the read/verify, as above, to validate the UPDATE
5. And finally **delete** that resource using a DELETE request, again relying on the env variable for the resource ID.

This approach works beautifully for one person doing the testing.  But since we seem to share the same environment variable pool, we end up stepping on each others toes randomly during the day.

Surely other teams are doing the same kind of CRUD testing.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the new Workspaces feature something that could potentially help you out? http://blog.getpostman.com/2018/02/27/postman-workspaces/

Comment: We're using workspaces, but that's part of the problem.  Being able to share request definitions is great, but sharing variables is the problem.  Because we all share the same cache of environment variables, there's the risk of one person's test run (that takes 5 or so minutes) overlapping another person's test run.  We talked about just creating separate "Environments" (which I believe is essentially a bag of variables), but some variables we DO want to share.  What we really need is something like "session variables", that are private to one session.

Comment: Could you have both? Add some variables that everyone can use at the Collection/ subfolder level that are used by everyone and then have your own environment files? I guess your own context and process will dictate what you can and cannot do. It does seem like a common problem that teams sharing collections are having, might be worth raising on there github project as a feature request?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I like the concept there, but unfortunately, env vars are grouped by "Environment", and you have to pick one "Environment" before each test run, so you can't pull vars from two different environments.  Will have a look at their Github project.